# Spatial query to make view

Tags: postgis, spatial-database, query

I've got two tables which I want to combine and enrich with each others data. I'm getting stuck on the join part, as this needs to be done via a spatial query.

First the table structure: a table with addresses and a table with ensembles.

**address**: zipcode | number | addition | geom_point
**ensemble**: id | ensemble_id | geom_polygon

The resulting table I want to achieve has a row for every address with the corresponding ensemble id. Corresponding means: where the `geom_point` is within `geom_polygon`.

There can be addresses which have their point outside of the geom_polygon. The ensemble ID should then remain `NULL`

Is it possible to use some kind of spatial function in the join part of a query?

```
SELECT a.*, e.ensemble_id
FROM address as a
LEFT JOIN ensemble as e ON [[a.geom_point within e.geom_polygon]]
```

Comment: Can you do joins without common field? Isn't this querry do what you want: `SELECT a.*, e.ensemble_id
FROM address as a, ensemble as e 
WHERE ST_Within(a.geom_point, e.geom_polygon)`. Plz clarify about `ensemble_id` - do you want to update it? If yes - with what an in which table?

Comment: There is no need to be able to update the table's. It's just a `view`. So the query you give should also be possible. There is indeed no common field between the two tables, except for the spatial 'common' field.

Comment: Do you need any further help?

Comment: Maybe I'm now trying the query's :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you need:

```
SELECT a.*, e.ensemble_id 
FROM address as a, ensemble as e  
WHERE ST_Within(a.geom_point, e.geom_polygon)
```